# Why am I getting 'cannot read property 'filter' of undefined' when the array being filtered contains JSON data?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, api, filter

The following code

```
const endpoint = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Hipo/university-domains-list/master/world_universities_and_domains.json';
const universities = [];

fetch(endpoint)
    .then(results => results.json())

    .then(data => universities.push(...data));

console.log(universities);

function findMatches(wordToMatch, universities) {
    return universities.filter(uni => {
        const regex = new RegExp(wordToMatch, 'gi');
        return uni.name.match(regex)
    })
}

export default findMatches;
```

returns the error below

> 'Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'filter' of undefined'

I can log the data using console.log(universities). So why can't I filter through it? FYI the data is an array of objects. Any help is massivaly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: how are you invoking findMatches

Comment: I'm surprised that `console.log` logs anything.

Comment: Note that `universities` inside `findMatches` is different scope variable than `const universities` unless that is what you pass in when you call findMatches()

Comment: you are getting it because you are trying to filter an array which contains json data.

Comment: Sorry Linas, I am invoking it in another file. I import it into my main app file, then call it in there too. The actual file is then bundled by webpack.

Comment: @Harry that doesn't make sense...JSON is a string data format and all arrays have filter prototype

Comment: You are getting 'cannot read property 'filter' of undefined' when the array being filtered contains JSON data.

Comment: No, he's getting 'filter' of undefined because his code is implicitly doing undefined.filter because in which ever way that he calls findMatches he doesn't give it an array as the second argument

Comment: @LinasMickevicius interesting. Is there any way I can make this findMatches() function dynamic? Reason being, I want to implement a typeahead search. I am currently unable to call the findMatches('hi") function in the console as it returns findMatches is not defined. Why is this so?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to remove `universities` as a parameter in your `findMatches` function because it is overriding the value of the local `universities` variable:

```
function findMatches(wordToMatch) {
    return universities.filter(uni => {
        const regex = new RegExp(wordToMatch, 'gi');
        return uni.name.match(regex)
    })
}
```

You can then proceed to use the `findMatches` function as follows:

```
findMatches("hi") // returns a filtered array
```

Edit:

You have a race condition in your code, wherein `findMatches` might be called 
before your `fetch` is complete. To fix the issue, `findMatches` should return a promise like so:

```js
const endpoint = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Hipo/university-domains-list/master/world_universities_and_domains.json';
const universities = [];

const promise = fetch(endpoint)
    .then(results => results.json())

    .then(data => universities.push(...data));

console.log(universities);

function findMatches(wordToMatch) {
    return promise.then(() => universities.filter(uni => {
        const regex = new RegExp(wordToMatch, 'gi');
        return uni.name.match(regex)
    }));
}

findMatches("hi").then(arr => console.log(arr));
```

If you're absolutely sure that `findMatches` will always be called after `fetch` is complete, you can go with the first solution. Otherwise, it is strongly recommended you go with the second solution that uses promises.

Comment: While you're correct I think the issue is that because `fetch` is an async function, the `universities` array _isn't_ populated when `findMatches` is exported. It's why I'm surprised that `console.log` works; it shouldn't - for the same reason.

Comment: You're correct @Andy -- I'm modifying my answer to correct the bug

Comment: Is there any way I can make this findMatches() function dynamic? Reason being, I want to implement a typeahead search.

I am currently unable to call the findMatches('hi") function in the console as it returns findMatches is not defined. Why is this so?

Comment: @Leafyshark are you using it in a different file? Do you have "export default findMatches;" at the bottom of file like you had in your example?

Comment: Yes, and I invoke it in the other file with a dynamic variable using findMatch( $('.search')) https://gist.github.com/paulirish/12fb951a8b893a454b32

Comment: @Leafyshark not sure if it's a typo in your comment, but the function call should be "findMatches" not "findMatch". As long as you are exporting the function and importing it correctly, the function should be defined. Can you provide more code?

Comment: It was a type @ChristianSantos sorry about that. I've currently got the code to log out the names based on search input. However, when I use innerHTML to render the names in my template, it renders as [object Promise] for some reason. Any ideas? I could send you the code somehow

Comment: @Leafyshark it sounds like you are using the value returned by `findMatches` directly, which you should not do as the value returned is a `Promise`. Instead, you should use `then()` to capture the value that the promise resolves to. For example, your code would be: `findMatches( $('.search') ).then( (filteredArr) => $('.some-element').html(filteredArr) );` -- notice that the `filteredArr` is only available inside the `then()` function

Answer (score 1):

I just want to let everybody know I finally got things working. I had to install babel-polyfill and babel-preset-env and add to webpack to get UglifyJS to work with async await and to optimise bundle size.

I had to use async await instead of regular promises to get the HTML to render into the DOM for some reason, not sure why. Anyway here is the code that finally worked as expected:

**UniFetch.js**

```
const endpoint = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Hipo/university-domains-list/master/world_universities_and_domains.json';

const universities = [];

const promise = fetch(endpoint)
    .then(blob => blob.json())
    .then(data => universities.push(...data.slice(8286, 8456)));

function findMatches(wordToMatch) {
    return promise.then(() => universities.filter(uni => {
        const regex = new RegExp(wordToMatch, 'gi');
        return uni.name.match(regex)
    }));
}

async function displayMatches() {
    searchResults.innerHTML = await findMatches(this.value)
        .then(arr => arr.map(uni => {
        return `
            <li>${uni.name}</li>
        `
    }));
}

const searchInput = document.querySelector("input[name='unisearch']");
const searchResults = document.querySelector('.unisearch__results');

searchInput.addEventListener('change', displayMatches);
searchInput.addEventListener('keyup', displayMatches);

export default findMatches
```

**App.js**

```
import FindMatches from '../UniFetch.js'

FindMatches()
```

Hope this helps some people to implement a typeahead, autocomplete API fetch.